# Unity NavMeshAgent not reaching target - moving around

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've created a simple scene and I'm now trying to make a rabbit move to the mouse-click position on a Plane.

So I've added a Rigidbody, a Nav Mesh Agent and a simple "Pathfinding" script to the rabbit.

The planes Mesh Renderer is set to "Navigation Static", "Generate OffMeshLinks" and "Walkable"

Now as soon as the rabbit gets close to the given destination, it will not stop but rather is "running around" in a very small circle around the destination.

Here is my script

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Pathfinding : MonoBehaviour {

private NavMeshAgent agent;
private Animator animator;

// Use this for initialization
void Start() {
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update() {
    RaycastHit hit;

    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
            agent.SetDestination(hit.point);
            animator.SetInteger("AnimIndex", 1);
            animator.SetBool("Next", true);
        }
    }
}
}
```

and a picture of my rabbit object ;)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Stopping Distance should be > 0

Comment: I've tried that (values 0,0.5,1,2,5,10), it only changes the radius of the circle

It looks like the rabbit is running towards the destination, but it does not stop at the stoppingdistance, I've created a short youtube video which shows the problem (with stoppingdistance 10)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbdYTZgJce8&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1):

Actually I was wrong, updating Unity didn't fix the problem, but I recognized that the problem was that the animations "Root Transformation Position (XZ)"/ Bake Into Pose was deactivated.

I also changed my script to

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Pathfinding : MonoBehaviour {

private NavMeshAgent agent;
private Animator animator;

private bool run = false;

// Use this for initialization
void Start() {
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update() {
    RaycastHit hit;

    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
            Debug.Log("start");
            agent.SetDestination(hit.point);
            animator.SetInteger("AnimIndex", 1);
            animator.SetBool("Next", true);
            run = true;
        }
    }else if(agent.remainingDistance <= agent.stoppingDistance && run) {
        Debug.Log("stop");
        animator.SetInteger("AnimIndex", 0);
        animator.SetBool("Next", true);
        run = false;
    }


}
}
```